# multi table inserts in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Looking for  a way to efficiently perform a multi-table insert in Postgres ( a bit like the INSERT ALL statement in Oracle). Lets say I have the following driver table:

```
ID, Data
----------------
10, 'Table 1 data'
11, 'Table 2 data'
10, 'More Table 1 data'
```

So, all ID=10 records should be inserted into table 1, ID=11 to table 2 etc ... The real driver table has >350 million records with around 12 distinct ID's so looking for way to do this efficiently as possible using just SQL.

Comment: Assuming you have only 12 distinct `ID` values, what would be wrong with just using 12 different insert statements?

Comment: That's 12 ( insert into  select ... where ... )  of a 350+ million record table. Of course I could do it that way, it would just take an age. A simple select count(*) of the table takes almost 3 minutes to run

Comment: For those of us not familiar with Oracle, could you give an example or link to what "INSERT ALL" does and how it would be used for your situation? That might help clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: What about table partitioning by id?

Comment: Please see this link for Oracle  https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/multitable-inserts. Specifically the Conditional INSERT ALL section